# Matlab Clustering : not working properly over large set of data

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, cluster-analysis

[image: Cluster analysis]

I have a set of data which can be separated into two groups. A vertical set along y axis and horizontal set along x axis. I was trying to plot them in blue and red respectively.  But as you can see, some blue has mixed with red.Could anyone please help me to do this correctly using clustering ?  I used kmeans to do this.

[cidx2,cmeans2] = kmeans(minSpikeV,2);

But it doesn't seem work well.

I did as mentioned by @mpaskov. But now I get this. those red rectangles should be blue squares. Can anyone please help me ?
[image]

Comment: As kmeans is a heuristic, that's typical behaviour sometimes (it guarantees only convergence to some local-optimum as the problem is a nonconvex-optimization problem with multiple local-minima; it's np-hard). The classic approach of adding more robustness to this it to cluster multiple times with different random-seeds (multi-start). mpaskov's answer gives some idea on how to do it manually (all the implementations i used already provide this functionality out of the box)

Comment: This data looks better suited for DBSCAN to me, but maybe the Matlab k-means just is not very good. Did you try clustering the data in ELKI instead?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse what is that?

Comment: My preferred tool for clustering. Very fast and many options to choose from. Try KMeansPlusPlusInitialization there, or farthest points.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will try that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use different way of initializing the means or specify them yourself.

```
% uses random samples
[cidx2,cmeans2] = kmeans(minSpikeV,2, 'Start', 'sample');

% not 100% on the dimensions, but I can not try as I do not have the toolbox for kmeans
[cidx2,cmeans2] = kmeans(minSpikeV,2, 'Start', [-0.05,2; -0.25,0.1]);
```

Have a read on the details in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html)

Comment: Thanks mpaskov and sascha. I am still trying to figure out what you say. Appreciate your help

Comment: @TMH Basically kmeans start with two value which are guesses on where the center for each cluster is. Then it performs iterations to improve them. If you started at a very bad point it might not converge and separate the two clusters. Modern kmeans algorithm try different starting points and use the 'best' one, not sure if matlab does that. But it does allow you to choose starting points where you expect the clusters to be centered around or different ways to start the algorithm.